# android picasso set and fetch identifier for cached image

Tags: android, image, caching, picasso

How can I set and fetch an identifier for the cached image in picasso?

Specifically, I want to set unix timestamp along with a image (which I'm calling as modified time).

Using picasso, I'm fetching some images from network and caching them. These images are profile images of users.

```
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture)
        .error(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture)
        .into(imageView);
```

On my server database, I maintain images' last modified time. So whenever I request a image, I want to first send the image modified time that I have locally, so that I can check whether modified time of the image has changed and then refetch image only if it has changed.

Algorithm:

1. Fetch picasso cached image modified time
2. Send this time to server
3. Server checks whether modified time for the image has changed.
4. If server replies yes, refetch the new image and set new modified time received from server in picasso. Else, do nothing.

I can do steps 2,3,4. But I'm not sure how step 1 can be done?

How can I set and fetch modified time (some identifier) for the image in picasso?

Comment: You can use Tag property to set loading time and operate accordingly

  Picasso.with(this)
                .load("Goole")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.image1)
                .error(R.drawable.image1)
                 .tag(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .into(new ImageView(this));

Comment: @bpAFree and how can i fetch it?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?